# How to expand a TreeItem till its last leaf node

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a `TreeViewer` wherein when the user selects a TreeItem and clicks on a button 'Expand', the entire hierarchy under the `TreeItem` shoul be opened till the last leaf node is found.

I have found an existing method on `TreeViewer` which would address my requirement i.e

```java
viewer.expandToLevel(item, level);
```

I have the selected item which I would pass as first argument to the above method, but how do I get the level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the special value `AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS` for this:

```
viewer.expandToLevel(object, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
```

Note: `object` is your data model object (from your content provider) **not** a `TreeItem`